# How to Make New Alt Code?

Tags: facebook, text, twitter, symbols, alt

And I mean a new alt code for using text symbols (like ☣ and ☫) on Facebook and other social networks? A client of mine wants me to make a text symbol of his logo to make his Facebook posts more original, but I can not find solution to this nowhere on the Web, only to use the existing text symbols... Is this even possible?

Comment: No, that is not possible. You can use defined emojis or special characters found in common fonts - but you can not use your own. (Sure, you can create your own font containing whatever symbol you want - but you won’t get Facebook to use your font on their website.)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. How unfortunate for the inability...